# Find out name of container that restarted, using Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Currently I am using the following query

```
sum(rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="default"}[5m]))
```

to get alerted when 1 or more container get restarted in default namespace.

This gives me the number of containers that restarted but not their names. Is there a way to get the name of containers that restarted?

Thanks you.

Comment: You can search for `Pods` that have been restarted by this query: `kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="NAMESPACE"} >= 1`. Is this what you are looking for? The `>=` is to show only containers with a value of `Restarts` set to 1 or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below query

```
sum (changes (kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[1m])) by (container,container_name,endpoint,instance,job,name,namespace, pod, pod_name,service)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the way you should approach the issue is to really understand what you need:

1. you need to get some meaningful information from the labels (name, namespace, etc.)
2. you need to get the proper value of the restarts that happened for a period of time
3. you need to get only the issues (since it is an alert, and not a graph).

Then I think you should consider this:

1. check out your labels - see which ones you need and which you don't. If you do that, you can even see that you don't need to use `sum` here. `sum` is an aggregation function that sums time series. If you expect to sum the number of restarts for 5m - this is not the case. There is another function - `sum_over_time` but it does not make sense for this particular metric (the metric is a counter). If you do not use sum, you will get all the labels. If you want to group the restars by some factor (for example you have pods that have multiple containers) - then you should use sum with `by (<label_1>, <label_2>, ...)`.
2. so you want to get the restarts for a given period of time (5m in your case). You have `kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total`, which is a counter. What a counter means in this sense is that whenever restart happens - the counter is increased. In the other replies it has been suggested that you use the `changes` function. This is OK, but it does not cover the case in which restarts happen so fast that Prometheus did not had time to acknowledge this - 0 to 3 to 5 to ... In this example, it is better to actually check what is the value now and compare it with what it was 5m ago. This can be done with `offset`:

```
kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="default"} - kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="default"} offset 5m
```

3. the way you structure PromQL code to do an alert, in this case, is to add a comparison binary operator. Simply said:

```
kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="default"} - 
kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="default"} offset 5m
> 0
```

That way you will get only those containers that restarted.

So to sum my reply - if I were you and I wanted to know which pods (not containers) had restarts in the last 5m and add all my meaningful information in the output, I would do something like:

```
sum by (pod, namespace, cluster)
(
  kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="default"} - 
  kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="default"} offset 5m
) > 0
```

Just make sure you check the labels... they differ from cluster to cluster and implementation to implementation (even exporter version).